# Can I use my old radiator valves when replacing the radiator itself?

Tags: radiator, plumbing-fixture

One of my Stelrad K1 radiators has died (corroded enough that there is a hole into it, and it's full of sludge and rust) so I'm going to replace it. It's a standard model, so should be a straight swap in, however:

The new one doesn't come with the pair of radiator valves - I can order them separately (once I have figured out what is meant by 15mm manual angled radiator valves and 8/10mm manual angled valves)

But can I just use the old ones?

Comment: Is this used for steam heat? Because most hydronic water heating systems (closed loop) that I have seen have minimal rust and sludge issues even after 50+ years.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by stream heating... But considering I mentioned sludge I'm guessing it's not that.

Comment: some radiators are heated by circulating hot water, and some work by being supplied with steam. For the steam heated radiators with a single pipe acting as both the supply and return, they are basically sludge and rust making factories. For steam heat you don't need to worry about old leaky valves as much, as long as you never need to turn it off.

Comment: No - this is a perfectly normal water one. 20 years old. And sadly dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, those valves usually have a shorter lifespan than the radiators they are connected to. I would recommend you replace the valve as many times old valves like leaking once you start messing with it.